# How to get the handle of application that received the mousedoubleclick?

Tags: c#, winapi, mousekeyhook

Is it possible to get the handle of the Window the user clicked (or in my case double-clicked) on?

Adding more detail:
I have an application that when launched by the user, watches for a specific hot key (CTL+SHIFT+T).  When pressed, my application sends a keyboard command back to the original application (CTL-C), then takes the text from the Clipboard and logs the text.
I am attempting to extend/replace the keyboard sequence with a double-click.   Is this possible?

Comment: Can you supply some context. Presumably you are trying to spy on some other program, or something like that.

Comment: I have an application that watches the keyboard  - when the user selects some text and pressed the defined keyboard sequence (in my case "CTL+T") my application sends a keyboard sequence back to the original app.  I've been asked to try to make this same process work with a double-click.

Comment: Please add the details to the question, rather than in comments. FWIW, your program will render most computers unusable. CTRL+T is a widely used shortcut.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

well according to what you explained in the comment you need to get the handle of foreground window when user press "CTL+T" to do what you want and in [this](http://www.csharpdeveloping.net/Snippet/how_to_get_active_window_handle_and_title) link it will show you how to get the handle of foreground window.

Comment: This is a very low quality answer. It contains no information and a link to who knows what. Please edit the answer to include at the very least a summary of what we will find should we follow your link.